# Remove Child AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I'm trying to remove a child movieclip but it's always get an error. I already tried different way and nothing works.

Here is my print screen. The Movieclip i want to remove is movieclip1 that is inside the movieclip playerPaddle.

Any help please.

my code to remove:

```
if(playerPaddle.movieclip1.hitTestObject(ball)){
                        playerPaddle.movieclip1.removeChild(movieclip1);

}
```

Error Message:
Dialog box saying dismiss all or continue - cannot converto movieclip1$ to flash.display.DisplayObject

Comment: Are you sure that `movieclip1` is a MovieClip?

Answer (score 2):

If i understood correctly, you're trying to remove movieclip1 from playerPaddle object.

To do this you have to call:

```
if(playerPaddle.movieclip1.hitTestObject(ball)){
                    playerPaddle.removeChild(playerPaddle.movieclip1);
```

}

And That is because playerPaddle is parent object of movieclip1 hence, calling removeChild on parent object will work perfectly.

Comment: Right - guys below are correct. My solution has small error. Addressing movieclip1 must be done with parent's name. Unless you declare a variable by the name movieclip1 which holds reference to nested movieclip :).

Answer (score 1):

While Kuba's answer brings up an issue with the code you've provided, but I think the issue you are facing right now is that `movieclip1` object that is passed as parameter to `playerPaddle.movieclip1.removeChild(...)` isn't a movieclip1. If I have to venture a guess, it most probably is null.

Can you try:

```
if(playerPaddle.movieclip1.hitTestObject(ball))
{
    playerPaddle.removeChild(playerPaddle.movieclip1);
}
```

(I've included the suggestion by Kuba too).

Answer (score 0):

the following may help you

```
if(this.parent) this.parent.removeChild(this);
```

you can replace `this` with the proper child and have the same result. like:

```
if(ball.parent) ball.parent.removeChild(ball);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kuba is almost correct, but movieclip1 will not be in scope. You still need to point to movieclip1 which is an object belonging to playerPaddle.

```
if(playerPaddle.movieclip1.hitTestObject(ball))
{
    playerPaddle.removeChild(playerPaddle.movieclip1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your removing the child you also need to remove the EventListener that is listening to the child.  If you remove the child object and the event listener is still checking for it, you will get an error.  You can nest the function in a check statement like this

```
    if(playerPaddle)
    {
        if(playerPaddle.movieclip1.hitTestObject(ball))
        {
            playerPaddle.removeChild(playerPaddle.movieclip1);
        }
    }
```